# How to trigger the smart contract externally?

Tags: solidity, ether, smart-contract-wallets

Is it possible to trigger the smart contract externally using solidity.

any methods to trigger external events into the smart contract.

Comment: I need more clarification about what you are trying to do. You can deploy the contract from within another contract by instantiating it and using a keyword `new` if that is what you are asking.

Comment: I need to pay the user in crypto when they complete some sort of task. my application is not on blockchain I need to achieve this using smart contract whenever they completes the task I need to pay them to pay I need to trigger my smart contract externally, so how can I achieve this.

Comment: You could just your aplication to web3 and send funds directly to other accounts. If you create a smart contract just for this it will cost deployment gas, and also what sort of task? why does it has to be a smart contract? This question needs more details

Answer (score 1):

You might need to implement a "pay" method in your smart contract and then interact with your smart contract using an address. But why don't you send funds directly using an address?